# Vim shortcut to pdflatex a specific tex file

Tags: pdftex, vim

I'm working on a document that is structured as follows:

```
/Document/
    |
    |--Chapter1/chap1.tex
    |
    |--Chapter2/chap2.tex
    |
    |--Chapter3/chap3.tex
    |
    \--main.tex
```

where the file `main.tex` includes the 3 chapter tex files shown.

Using Vim, I edit each of the files `chap1.tex`, `chap2.tex`, and `chap3.tex` often.  I want to configure a shortcut so that within the Vim editor, I can enter something like

`:buildme`

which will cause the following terminal command will be executed:

`$ cd .. ; pdflatex 'main.tex'`

Comment: Do you use `vim-latex-suite`?

Comment: @m0nhawk No, I don't.  I usually use Winefish for tex, and Vim for general text editing purposes.  But I'm thinking about switch my tex editing to Vim.

Comment: In `vim-latex-suite` you can use [this](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html). That's, I think, the most pretty way to do this.

Comment: @m0nhawk very cool.  Thanks.  I will definitely give `vim-latex-suite` a try.  Looks very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User commands need to start with a capital letter;  try the following:

```
 command! Buildme exec('cd ..|!pdflatex main.tex')
```